# Dynamically binding of Dataset to RDLC Reports

Tags: c#, report, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I would like to bind the dynamically dataset to the rdlc.  I can view the report if I use inline DataSource in ASPX file (static binding).  However, if I use the following codes, the Report viewer keeps showing "Loading.." Image.

I have already check the dataset name and if I changed the dataset name to "Orders2", it shows me that required dataset "Orders" is not provided.  So, I add the GridView on the form and test my DataSet.  The dataset contains data and showing well with the GridView.

The problem is only with the Report and I could not bind data dynamically to the ReportViewer.  Please help me.  Thanks.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = GetDataSet();
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("Orders", ds.Tables[0]);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

private DataSet GetDataSet()
{
    var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dotnetConnectionString"];
    string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "Select * FROM Orders";

    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();        
    ad.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
```

ASPX codes are as below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="600px" Width="800px">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\Report.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you share how is your design of RDLC.? If we are binding data set dynamically then what about the rdlc design.?

Comment: Did you still need to design the rdlc file beforehand? Or did you just create the rdlc file, without inserting any tables or binding it? Ive tested it, if i design it first - creating table and bind with dataset, it shows perfectly. But based on your main question, i thought that you do it dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already solved my problem.

The problem is you need to add your codes under IsPostBack wrapping.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
//your binding codes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Pade_load event, add this code

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("\\Reports\\Report.rdlc");
this.ReportViewer1.Width = 800;
this.ReportViewer1.Height = 600;
```