# Filling rdlc report via asp.net code

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, report, c#-3.0, rdlc

I am trying to fill RDLC report with Typed dataset. I am trying to fill it via code but don't know that what to Put in specific places.

Name of dataset is GPSDBDataSet.XSD, Name of Report if Report.rdlc, Name of datatable is Coordinates.

using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportViewer1.Visible = true;

            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();

            ReportViewer1.Reset();

            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

            LocalReport rep = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;                      

            rep.Refresh();

            rep.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";


            rds.Name = ???????;


            rds.Value = ????;

            rep.DataSources.Add(rds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652347/dynamically-binding-of-dataset-to-rdlc-reports

Comment: didn't help, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its been a while, but try this.

rds.name = "yourdatasetname" // in your case this till be coodinates

rds.value = ds.table[0];

Code
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

```
try
{
    ds = RetrieveData();//some func that returns dataset...
    ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
    // Must match the DataSource in the RDLC
    reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";//coordinates in your case.
    reportDataSource.Value = ds.Tables[0];
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Error Generating the Report", Ex);
}
```

Comment: Report Viewer Configuration Error

The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered

Comment: You need to add few lines to your web.config and you will be all set.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1360494.aspx?IIS+7+and+Reportviewer

Its a very common problem and googling that error text will show you  alot of results.